# How to install Puppet Enterprise Agent Installation without Internet on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, puppet

I have installed PE 3.7.x successful on CentOS 6.5 -64 bit OS and all works.

Now I am installing PE Agent on another node on CentOS 6.5 -64 bit OS, but this node is not connected to the Internet.
I followed the Puppet Docs, and per instruction, I downloaded the PE Agent 3.7.x agent version and copied the tar ball on Master in `/opt/staging/pe-repo`

Now  when I execute

```
curl -k https://192.168.1.1:8140/packages/current/install.bash| sudo bash
```

it still goes to search Internet Mirror sites and eventually fails with the Install.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet installs a lot of packages (for dependency) when your start the installer from external repo. 
A possible solution is to setup your own mirror from the puppet repo within your network (maybe on your master).

After adding that internal repo all packges will get installed from the repo on your master.

You can find the puppet repo here => https://yum.puppetlabs.com/